# Array of static char* 's

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I would like to know if it is correct C++ :

```
static char *arrayExample[]  = 
{
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d",
    "e",
    "f",
    "g",
    "h"
};
```

Comment: No, non-constant pointers to string literals are a horrible misdeed, deprecated in C++03 and plain wrong in C++11.

Comment: So to summarize: it's legal, but wrong.

Comment: @pava91 its absolutely correct but it gives problem when you reallocating its memory.

Comment: @chris Are you sure about the versions there? I was thinking along the same lines, but just tried it with `g++` 4.7.2; without `--std=c++11` it compiled with no complaint, and with the flag I got `warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'`.

Comment: As already noted it's not correct (misses a `const` before the `*`), but I just wanted to add that this is not really an _"array of static `char*`s"_ but rather a _"static array of `char*`s"_ (`static` applies to the array, not the individual elements).

Comment: @BoBTFish: Yes, chris is correct. The exception that allows the conversion is in paragraph 4.2/2 of [the 2003 standard](http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring13/CSCI-GA.2110-001/downloads/C++%20Standard%202003.pdf), with a note that it is deprecated.  This paragraph is entirely removed for [the 2011 standard](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf), meaning there is no longer an exception.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Ah, I see, my compiler is just being confusing. Thanks.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, No wonder I couldn't find it. The best I found was `char* p = "abc"; // valid in C, invalid in C++` in § C.1.1.

Comment: @BoBTFish, Yes, I know GCC just warns. It really should give an error. At least a warning is better than nothing.

Answer (score 5):

> I would like to know if is correct write that in C++

```
static char *arrayExample[]  = 
{
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d",
    "e",
    "f",
    "g",
    "h"
};
```

Does it compile even if you don't add the `const` modifier? Yes, but it is misleading. String literals are stored in memory area in which all string literals of the source code are saved, one after another. This means that you should not mess with it (in a PC it won't happen. but it could be mapped to ROM memory).

So, it is basically correct. However, this array of literals is not meant to be modified, so you should better rewrite it to be:

```
static const char *arrayExample[]  = 
{
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d",
    "e",
    "f",
    "g",
    "h"
};
```

You have declared it to be `static`: this means that it will only be visible in its own translation unit (i.e. the very cpp file in which it was created). If that's what you intended (you did not intend to be able to share it among translation units), then it is perfectly okay.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Baltasard please tell me if I declare variable as static then can we changes its value through out the program??

Comment: No, @Iamhere. When declaring a variable as static, you will only be able to access (and thus modify it) in the very same translation unit (i.e., cpp file) it was defined on. It would therefore not make sense to declare a static variable in a header file.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to compile with `-Wall` the compiler warns you

> warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’

An array of "x" constant strings makes the initialization of the array, while the declaration is only

```
static char *
```

This is not wrong per say, but you may try to modify an item of the array like

```
*arrayExample[2] = 'x'; // runtime error / crash / undefined behavior
```

Adding *const* removes the compiler warning(s), and prevents you from writing some code that would overwrite the read-only values, which would compile, but would crash at runtime. `const` will have the compiler stops with an error (not a warning) when trying to overwrite one of the `char *` item of the array.

```
static const char *
```

Comment: That would be cool. However in C and C++ there are almost no "runtime error angels" but just "undefined behavior daemons" instead.

Comment: Usually `Segmentation fault` ... I actually added *undefined behavior* before your comment...